# CSRF disable doesn't work in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I'm currently testing a REST API with Spring Security. Because this is just testing, I'm disabling CSRF. With the code below, a Postman get request to /users works perfectly, but any other type of request from Postman (e.g. post, delete, put) give me back a 403 FORBIDDEN error. Really can't figure it out.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Comment: and your debug logs tell you?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf no, I'm not getting any messages

Comment: your spring security debug logs will tell you exactly why you are getting a forbidden back, unless you are calling a from a web browser, then check the web browser console (F12) and you will have the reason for the forbidden there. Update your question with the spring security logs

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Where would I find those logs? There's nothing showing up in my console.

Comment: i have no idea how you are running your application, its different depending if you are running in eclipse, intellij, netbeans, command line etc. if you dont know how to find/read the logs, i suggest you learn that first, and how to debug your application before you try out spring security.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I'm running it with Tomcat on Spring Tool Suite; usually the console is where I get error messages, but I'm not getting anything useful on either the console or Postman. I can't imagine where else I would find any logs.

Comment: well if you don't get any logs i would focus on that first and you should focus on learning how to get debug logs from spring security, because i have no idea what the answer to your question is until we see the logs. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any cors configuration setup to allow methods other than "GET"?

You can create a `CorsConfigurationSource` bean that should allow access to those types of requests

```java
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    private static final String[] CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS = new String[] {
        "*",
    };

    private static final String[] CORS_ALLOWED_METHODS = new String[] {
        "GET",
        "POST",
        "PUT",
        "OPTIONS"
    };

    private static final String CORS_API_PATTERN = "/api/**";

    private static final long CORS_MAX_AGE = 3600;

    @Value("${cors.allowed-origins}")
    private String[] corsAllowedOrigins;

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(corsAllowedOrigins));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(CORS_ALLOWED_METHODS));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setMaxAge(CORS_MAX_AGE);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS));

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration(CORS_API_PATTERN, configuration);

        return source;

    }
```